# GET Shiftpreferences through Microsoft-Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get Shiftpreferences.
My admin consented to all displayed permissions in the Graph Explorer.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myUserID}/settings/shiftpreferences

Forbidden - 403 - 272ms. You need to consent to the permissions on the Modify permissions tab
reponse: 403 - error "code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError"
```

No additional permissions are visible to consent to.

I wonder what could be the issue.

Thank you.